# Determine a class's metaclass in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaclass

In Python 2, I could check a class's `__metaclass__` attribute to determine its metaclass.

How do I the same thing in Python 3?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the single-argument `type` function (`type(class)`), or just access `class.__class__`.  Both of these work in Python 2, btw.

E.g.,

```
In [4]: class MyMetaclass(type): pass

In [5]: class MyClass(metaclass=MyMetaclass): pass

In [6]: type(MyClass)
Out[6]: __main__.MyMetaclass
```